# How to replace the overridden methods with a Recursive implementation

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, string-parsing

I want to use **recursion** in order to collapse the overridden `add()` methods in the code and allow the user to provide any number of terms.

I've made a couple of changes to my code, but I'm not getting the desired result.

Examples of user input and expected output.

**Output** (for input `3 + 4`)

```
7.0
```

**Output** (for input `3 + 4 + 5`)

```
12.0
```

The **code** I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String exp = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(solver(exp.split(" ")));

    }
    public static double solver(String[] expression) {

        double result = 0;

        if (expression.length == 3) {
            result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]));
        }
        else if (expression.length == 5) {
            result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[4]));
        }
        else if (expression.length == 7) {
            result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[4]), Double.parseDouble(expression[6]));
        }
        else if (expression.length == 9) {
            result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[4]), Double.parseDouble(expression[6]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[8]));
        }
        else if (expression.length == 11) {
            result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[4]), Double.parseDouble(expression[6]),
                    Double.parseDouble(expression[8]), Double.parseDouble(expression[10]));
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static double add(double a, double b) {return a + b;}
    public static double add(double a, double b, double c) {return a + b + c;}
    public static double add(double a, double b, double c, double d) {return a + b + c + d;}
    public static double add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e) {return a + b + c + d + e;}
    public static double add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {return a + b + c + d + e + f;}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like they want you to have only one add method with a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) parameter. And use recursion in the add method to add the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That's doable with **recursion**.

But before diving into ***recursive implementation***, it's worth to find out how to solve this problem ***iteratively*** because it'll give you a better understanding of what the *recursion* does.

Firstly, I want to point out at *issues* with the code you've provided.

Your existing solution is *brittle* since it depends on the consistency of  the user input, and it will fail because of the single additional white space or if a white space will be missing.

Another draw-back is that you have a *lot of methods* and with them, you are able to handle only a *limited number* of arguments in the given expression. Let's fix it.

Since your code is intended to perform the *arithmetical addition*, I think it'll be better to split the input on the *plus symbol* `+` and give a user a bit of freedom with white spaces.

For that, we need to pass the following regular expression into the `split()` method:

```
"\\s*\\+\\s*"
```

- **\s***  -  implies `0` or more white spaces;
- **\+**  -  plus symbol has a special meaning in regular expressions and needs to be escaped with a back-slash.

And since there's more than one arithmetical operation (*and you also might want to implement others letter on*). It's better to extract your the logic for splitting the user input into a separate method:

```
public static double add(String expression) {
    return addIteratively(expression.split("\\s*\\+\\s*"));
}
```

`expression.split()` will return an *array of numeric strings* that will allow to substitute all your methods with a **single method** that expects a *string array* `String[]` or *varargs* `String... expression` (*which will allow you to pass as an argument either an array of strings or arbitrary number of string values*).

```
public static double addIteratively(String[] operands) {
    double result = 0;
    for (String next: operands) {
        result += Double.parseDouble(next);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, when it's clear how to deal with this task **iteratively** (*remember every problem and could be addressed using **iteration** is also eligible for **recursion** and vice versa*) let's proceed with a quick recap on **recursion**.

Every recursive method consists of two parts:

- **Base case** - that represents a simple *edge-case* (condition when recursion terminates) for which the outcome is known in advance.
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where *recursive calls* are made and where the main logic resides.

To process the given array recursively, we can track the *position* in the array by passing it with each method call.

The **base case** will represent a situation when there's no more elements left in the array, i.e. current *position* is equal to the *array's length*. Since there's no element under the given *position*, the return is `0`.

In the **recursive case** we need to parse the number under the current position and add the result of the *recursive call* with *position* incremented by `1` to it. That will give us the *return value*.

The **recursive implementation** might look that:

```
public static double addAsDouble(String[] operands, int pos) {
    if (pos == operands.length) { // base case
        return 0;
    }
    // recursive case
    return Double.parseDouble(operands[pos]) + addAsDouble(operands, pos + 1);
}
```

Method responsible for splitting the *user input*.

```
public static double add(String expression) {
    return addAsDouble(expression.split("\\s*\\+\\s*"), 0); // recursion starts at position 0
}
```

`main()` - here, you just need to call the `add()` providing a string inter by the user and bother of what is happening inside add. That makes code cleaner and easier to read.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String exp = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(add(exp));
}
```

**Output**

```
3 + 4 +5
12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct indexes to the various add methods. For example, if you want to add three numbers, you should do the following:

```
result = add(Double.parseDouble(expression[0]), Double.parseDouble(expression[1]), Double.parseDouble(expression[2]));
```